# WSO2 Stream Processor metrics

Tags: wso2-streaming-integrator

What are the JMX metrics exposed by WSO2 Stream Processor? I'm particularly interested in number of events processed successfully, failed events, latency for event processing, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSO2 SP exposes the following metrics.

**Overall node metrics**

1. CPU usage
2. Metrics usage
3. Overall throughout of events
4. System load average
   Upcoming in future release
5. Event syncing throughputs in HA environment

**Siddhi App metrics**

1. RDBMS table insert, update, etc throughputs
2. Siddhi query throughout
3. Memory usage for siddhi queries
4. Source and Sink's throughput and latencies
5. Buffered events in Siddhi Windows
6. Throughput in Siddhi streams
   Upcoming in future release
7. Aggregation related metrics

What do you mean by "failed events" ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have enabled wso2.metrics in wso2-sp-4.0.0/conf/worker/deployment.yaml file. I am seeing only JVM metrics on the console. Can you please tell me how to get Siddhi App metrics?

Comment: Got it - https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP400/Viewing+Statistics+for+Siddhi+Applications